# い-adjectives derived from verbs

Tags: grammar, adjectives, history, i-adjectives

Some い-adjectives are derived somehow from verbs. For instance, 忙しい is related to 急ぐ according to Wiktionary.

Are there many い-adjectives derived from verbs? If a given verb has an adjectival form, can you reliably predict the pronunciation? Is there a list of adjectives that come from verbs?

(I assume that this derivational process is no longer productive and that most verbs don't have adjectival forms like this. Is that right?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there many い-adjectives derived from verbs?

There are quite a few. For example...

[勇]{いさ}む → 勇ましい
[痛]{いた}む → 痛ましい
[苛立]{いらだ}つ → 苛立たしい
[疑]{うたが}う → 疑わしい
[疎]{うと}む → 疎ましい
[恨]{うら}む → 恨めしい
[羨]{うらや}む → 羨ましい
[恐]{おそ}る → 恐ろしい
[好]{この}む → 好ましい
[騒]{さわ}ぐ → 騒がしい
[荒]{すさ}む → [凄]{すさ}まじい
[悩]{なや}む → 悩ましい
[妬]{ねた}む → 妬ましい
[似付]{につ}く → 似付かわしい
[望]{のぞ}む → 望ましい
[喜]{よろこ}ぶ → 喜ばしい
[煩]{わずら}う → 煩わしい
This is not an exhaustive list. There are also [慎]{つつ}ましい、[思]{おも}わしい、[呪]{のろ}わしい、ふさわしい、[輝]{かがや}かしい、[懐]{なつ}かしい、[行]{ゆ}く→ゆかしい(cf奥ゆかしい) etc...

> If a given verb has an adjectival form, can you reliably predict the pronunciation?

Most follow the `-u → -ashii` pattern, (e.g. isogu → isog**a**shii) but there are also `-u → -oshii` (e.g. osoru → osor**o**shii), `-u → -eshii` (e.g. uramu → uram**e**shii) and even `-u → -ajii` (e.g. susamu → susama**j**ii), `-u → -awashii` (e.g. nitsuku → nitsuka**wa**shii) so I'm not sure.

> Is there a list of adjectives that come from verbs?

I searched on the Internet but I couldn't find a list.

> (I assume that this derivational process is no longer productive and that most verbs don't have adjectival forms like this. Is that right?)

I think you're right (but I'm not an expert so excuse me if I'm wrong).

Comment: あと、(仲)睦まじい、願わしい、狂おしい、頼もしい、誇らしい、微笑ましい、腹立たしい、嘆かわしい、涙ぐましい、目覚ましい、とかもそれっぽいですけどどうなんでしょう。　ちなみに「優しい」が「痩す」（→痩せる）の形容詞化って辞書に書いてあって驚きでした